# how to dynamically pass chart data to shared chart component in angular 10 with chartJS

Tags: angular, chart.js

I have created a shared component for displaying the charts using chart.js, it is working fine with the mock/static data but when i try to pass dynamic data it is not showing anything.

here is what i have tried [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-starter-project-daidh-kefwpn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fdata.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftypes%2Fchart-types.enum.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftypes%2Fcommon.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

shared Component : app/components/chart
parent comp : app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem with *ngIf

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dataSets[0].data.length > 0 && labels.length > 0">
  <app-chart
    [type]="chartType.Line"
    [dataSets]="dataSets"
    [labels]="labels"
    [options]="options"
  ></app-chart>
</ng-container>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-starter-project-daidh-du6mjz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fchart%2Fchart.component.ts)